# Limit of $r^n$ as a recursively defined sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Solve for the limit of $a_n=r^n$ by treating it as a recursive sequence defined as $a_0=1$, $a_n=r*a_n_-_1$. (Let $r>0$ be a positive real number and $n>0$).

Now I really don't know how to solve for the limit since $r$ is arbitrary and not a concrete number.

Also, I am new here so I don't know how to format yet. Sorry...

Comment: Do you mean $a_n=r\cdot a_{n-1}$?

Comment: yeah that's what I meant!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the definition of a sequence which goes to infinity? Using that, you can show that ${\{a_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ goes to $\infty$ (it does not converge) if $r > 1$. If $r = 1$, then $a_n = 1$ for all $n = 1 , 2 , \ldots$, so its limit goes to $1$. On the other hand, using the definition of a convergent sequence, you can show that ${\{a_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ goes to $0$ when $r < 1$ ($r > 0$).